# Unity - unable to list all scenes in a project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene-manager

In my app, I wanted to get a list of certain scenes and their build indices at start up of a particular scene. The probability is that none of the scenes has yet been loaded.

To do this I tried `SceneManager.GetSceneByName()` - I have the names of the relevant scenes. Nothing came back.

Looking at the docs it seemed this should work. However looking at the similar `GetSceneByIndex()` that does state it only works for loaded scenes, and I am assuming - thought it does not say so - the same applies to `GetSceneByName()`.

So, I have not managed to find a way of listing all the available, but maybe not yet loaded, scenes. So far I have hard coded the relevant build indicies but I do not like that.

is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general it makes sense that you can not get any reference to a `Scene` that is not loaded yet. Even using [`SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex.html) states

> This method will return a valid Scene if a Scene has been added to the build settings at the given build index AND **the Scene is loaded. If it has not been loaded yet the SceneManager cannot return a valid Scene.**

---

What you **can** get however are at least all scene paths/names by using  [`SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex.html) by iterating over [`SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneCountInBuildSettings.html)

```
int sceneCount = SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings;     
string[] scenes = new string[sceneCount];

for( int i = 0; i < sceneCount; i++ )
{
   scenes[i] = SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex(i);
}
```

These would be the full scene paths. If you rather only want the scene name itself (but possible duplicates) you could probably instead use

```
scenes[i] = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex(i));
```